# Unclear on how to properly implement a daily cycle of timed events. Lots of confusion while trying to use Rx with Events and Enum

Tags: events, enums, task, system.reactive

I'm trying to create a class that does my Work. To set different states during the day I tried to use an enum:

```
public enum WorkState
{

    BeforeWork = Interval.Hr * 6 + Interval.Min * 30,
    Work= Interval.Hr * 9 + Interval.Min * 30,
    OverTime= Interval.Hr * 16 + Interval.Min * 00,
    Sleep= Interval.Hr * 20 + 00,
}
public enum Interval
{
    Sec = 1000,
    Min = Sec * 60,
    Hr = Min * 60,
    Day = Hr * 24,
    Week = Day * 7
}



public partial class Work:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private WorkEventArgs workEventArgs;
    private event EventHandler<WorkEventArgs> StateChanged;
    private WorkState _workState;

    public WorkState CurrentState
    {
        get { return _workState; }
        private set
        {

                _workState = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentState));


        }
    }


    private MarketState GetMarketStateWhen(DateTime givenTime)
    {
    return
            (MarketState)
                MarketTimeList.Where(x => x.TotalMilliseconds < givenTime.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds).Max().TotalMilliseconds;
    }



    private async void CountDownNextStateChange()
    {
        int nextStateStartTime =
            (int)
                WorkTimeList.Where(x => x.TotalMilliseconds > DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds)
                    .Min()
                    .TotalMilliseconds;

        Task t = Task.Delay(nextStateStartTime - (int) Math.Floor(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds));
        await t;
        CurrentState = (WorkState) nextStateStartTime;
    }

    public IObservable<EventHandler<WorkEventArgs>> ObserveWorkPhase { get; set; }

    public Work()
    {
        PropertyChanged += Work_PropertyChanged;
        CurrentState = GetWorkStateWhen(DateTime.Now);

        StateChanged += DispatchTasks;

        //----I tried a few different things with Observables and between all the hit and trial I'm not sure what worked what didn't so I just deleted all of it. But I think that's the way to go with this...but everything I've read just leaves me more confused.
        //var ob = Observable.FromEventPattern<WorkEventArgs>(handler=> StateChanged += handler,
        //    handler=> StateChanged -=handler);

        //    ob.Subscribe(x => );
        //stateChanges.Subscribe(data=>)
        //,.Invoke(this, new WorkEventArgs {}),onNext=> {},)
    }

    private void Work_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        workEventArgs = new WorkEventArgs()
        {
            ActiveTradingDay = DateTime.Parse("2015-12-13")
        }


        StateChanged?.Invoke(this, new WorkEventArgs());
        CountDownNextStateChange();
    }

    private Task ActLikeDoingSomeWork(WorkState tokenForWorkForThisState) => Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (CurrentState == tokenForWorkForThisState)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for " + CurrentState + " to change...Sleep 10sec!");
        }
    });


    private void DispatchTasks(object sender, WorkEventArgs e)
    {
        _workState = e.CurrentState;
        var workState = CurrentState;

        switch (e.CurrentState)
        {
            //Just faking some tasks 
            case (WorkState.PreWork):
                ActLikeDoingSomeWork(workState);
                break;

            case (WorkState.WorkOpen):
                ActLikeDoingSomeWork(workState);

                break;
            case (WorkState.AfterWork):
                ActLikeDoingSomeWork(workState);

                break;
            case (WorkState.Closed):
                ActLikeDoingSomeWork(workState);

                break;
        }

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName=null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

I'm sure there are a lot of things I could be doing (or should not be doing). I'm open to any guidance.

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: I'm trying to build a timetable for a day and there are classes that activate only during specific time. I was thinking of building a tv shows tracker. It would get reviews and summary after the show has aired. There are a lot of different work tasks I can think of where I can easily apply the same concept